# Can I set an entire membership type to expire, or cease to auto-renew?

Tags: civimember, auto-renew

I have a membership type which  can auto-renew, and is monthly for a fixed amount of time after which it ends on a specific date. Can I set that up so that the membership automatically ends for all members? Essentially, I want auto-renew to turn off on that date, for everyone. I can go through and do it manually if necessary, but I'd really love the solution to be scalable, and automatic would be much better.

Comment: Bump? I'd still really love an answer to this one.